# Deploy .bna file to docker

Tags: docker, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have now finished my business network definition on the docker composer online playground with bluemix but cannot figure out how I can deploy my .bna file that I got to a docker container.

The situation is this. I am working on a project with others developing on Windows machines. I want to deploy the .bna file in a Dockerfile with the composer rest server so that they clone the repo, do a docker run and it works out configured. Can someone please link me an article of how to do that.

Thank you

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

A Composer business network runs as chaincode on hyperledger fabric. The online playground provides a simulation of the composer runtime for you to get started with composer. But your goal will be to develop a business network and deploy it to a real hyperledger fabric environment. Composer website has lots of tutorials but I suggest you look at this one first
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org
It describes how to deploy a business network to a simple single org hyperledger fabric environment